# Evaluate higher order derivative at some point under some assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, evaluation

I need to evaluate the $k^{\rm th}$ order derivative

```
D[w[t] w'[t], {t, k}]
```

which is actually equal to

```
Sum[Binomial[k, j] D[w[t], {t, k - j + 1}] D [w[t], {t, j}], {j, 0, k}]
```

at `t = 0`. I am given that `w[0]==0` and `w'[0]==0`.

I am trying

```
Evaluate[D[w[t] w'[t], {t, 2}] /. t -> 0]
```

and then

```
FullSimplify[3 w'[0]w''[0] + w[0]w'''[0], Assumptions -> w[0] == 0 && w'[0] == 0]
```

but this works only for fixed `k`.

Is there a way to do the evaluation at `t = 0` under the asuumptions `w[0]==0` and `w'[0]==0` for arbitrary `k` and also take into account the value of evaluations up to `k-1` order? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that

```
w''[t] = f[t] - w[t] w'[t]
```

where `f[t]` is a given function. So that

```
D[w[t] w'[t], {t, k}] = D[w[t], {t, k + 2}] - D[f[t], {t, k}]
```

Thus,

```
w''[0] = f[0]

w'''[0] = f'[0] - Evaluate[D[w[t]w'[t], {t, 1}]/.t->0]
```

etc. I need the eventual formula to take these values into account as well.

Comment: `Sum[Binomial[k, j] D[w[t], {t, k - j + 1}] D[w[t], {t, j}], {j, 2, k - 1}]`?

Comment: Thank you! But that accounts only for `w[0] == 0` and `w'[0] == 0`. What I am mainly interested in, is to account for intermediate values, like `w''[0]`, `w'''[0]`, etc.

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you want to set `w''[0]` etc. equal to some given values?

Comment: Sorry for misleading. Your suggestion was quite obvious and evidently correct. But why the summation goes from `j = 2` to `j = k - 1`?

Comment: From the formula, one can see that those are the terms that do not contain `w[0]` or `w'[0]`.